# Control the run time of a python thread from outside

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I am trying to spawn a python thread which perform a particular operation repeatedly based on a certain condition. If the condition doesn't met then the thread should exit. I have written the following code, but its running indefinitely.

```
class dummy(object):
def __init__(self):
    # if the flag is set to False,the thread should exit
    self.flag = True

def print_hello(self):
    while self.flag:
        print "Hello!! current Flag value: %s" % self.flag
        time.sleep(0.5)

def execute(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_hello())
    t.daemon = True # set daemon to True, to run thread in background
    t.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    obj = dummy()
    obj.execute()
    #Some other functions calls
    #time.sleep(2)
    print "Executed" # This line is never executed
    obj.flag = False
```

I am new to python threading module. I have gone through some articles suggesting the use of `threading.Timer()` function, but this is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The problem line is `t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_hello())`, more specifically `target=self.print_hello()`. This sets `target` to the results of `self.print_hello()`, and since this function never ends it will never be set. What you need to do is set it to the function itself with `t = threading.Thread(target=self.print_hello)`.